# How to remove the lines and background color in ggplot?

Tags: r

I am using the `Palmerpenguins` Package. I would like to color my titles in purple, center the main title, include font 14, but most important change the background in white without lines and grey color- I am working with ggplot.

source title at the bottom? how?

```
ggplot(data = napenguins,  aes(x = species, y = island)) +
  xlab('Soorten pinquïns ')+
  ylab('Eiland')+
  ggtitle('Soorten pinquïns per eiland')+
  
  geom_jitter(aes(color = species),
              width = 0.3,
              alpha = 0.7,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#527f85","#7d9cf6","#f08fff"))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `+ theme_bw(base_size = 14) + theme(title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(color = "purple"))` will be a good start. See the examples at the bottom of the `?theme` help page for lots of examples.

Comment: or maybe they prefer `theme_classic()` @GregorThomas, post as answer?

Answer (score 2):

All the customizations you are asking for can be done in the `theme` function. This will be a pretty good start:

```
ggplot(data = napenguins,  aes(x = species, y = island)) +
  xlab('Soorten pinquïns ')+
  ylab('Eiland')+
  ggtitle('Soorten pinquïns per eiland')+
  
  geom_jitter(aes(color = species),
              width = 0.3,
              alpha = 0.7,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#527f85","#7d9cf6","#f08fff")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(
    title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "purple")
  )
```

See `?theme` for more options (especially the examples at the bottom). Or browse more base themes in the [ggthemes package](https://yutannihilation.github.io/allYourFigureAreBelongToUs/ggthemes/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `theme_void()`

```
ggplot(data = napenguins,  aes(x = species, y = island)) +
  xlab('Soorten pinquïns ')+
  ylab('Eiland')+
  ggtitle('Soorten pinquïns per eiland')+
  
  geom_jitter(aes(color = species),
              width = 0.3,
              alpha = 0.7,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#527f85","#7d9cf6","#f08fff")) +
theme_void()
```